# C# connection time

Tags: c#, connection

I'd like to have a connection time for a user, like getting the system date when a user connects, and getting the date when he disconnects and doing the difference between them.

Is it a pre-made way to do it in C# ?

Comment: (dis)connects to/from what? but probably not regardless

Comment: Are you working on a website - is it Session you are looking for?

Comment: Please be more specific. What kind of "connection" are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
DateTime startDate;
DateTime endDate;
public void Connect()
{
    //Do something
    startDate = DateTime.Now;
}
public void Disconnect()
{ 
   //Do something
   endDate = DateTime.Now;
   Console.Writeline(endDate.Subtract(startDate).TotalMinutes.ToString(););
}
```

Comment: It was a mistake. Thanks